# Copy Object Amazon S3 "The specified key does not exist"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy some files from bucket to another. I checked the Amazon S3 AWS console the file exist with the correct key. I tried to use `getObject` and it is returning the object without errors.

```
 $obj = $this->__s3->getObject(array(
                'Bucket' => 'tme.project.mi',
                'Key' => '329/42329.jpg',
            ));
```

this return the object correctly

```
 $this->__s3->copyObject(array(
                'Bucket' => 'tme.project.mi',
                'Key' => '329/42329.jpg',
                'CopySource' => "tme.project/{$data->id}/{$media->id}.{$media->ext}",
            ));
```

this returns `exception error "The specified key does not exist."`

Comment: It might be useful to see what the request looks like when it is sent over the wire. Try [attaching the wire logger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-see-what-data-is-sent-over-the-wire).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the source bucket was in US and the destination in origin.
i don't know why it's not copying from bucket that is has different location.

Comment: You cannot copy across regions with `CopyObject`. You effectively have to download the object and upload the object to the other location.